# How do make this 2D animation in Blender?

Tags: animation

[image]

How do I make animation in Blender

1. Tried - Divide the circle in 12 vertices, place 12 plane rectangles  (Clock Hands) in 12 circle vertices  rotate 30 degree (Array Modifier ) and then how do I move each and ever clock hands to form TIME Text?
2. May be reverse - Divide the TIME Text in to 12 equal parts and then map each and every plane rectangle to circle vertices - HOW TO DO and with smooth animations

Please guide

Comment: with an Array/Object Offset you can create the 12 rectangles, for the clock hands create 2 rectangles with their origin on their extremity so that they can easily rotate around, then move and scale all these rectangles so that they compose the TIME text, use a background image as a reference

Answer (score 1):

This is quite simple:

- Create a plane (12 o'clock tick) - resize as necessary, in edit mode move the object so the center is outside the shape (if you use "absolute grid snap" everything is easier)

[image]

- To create the 12 clock's lines, you just need to duplicate and rotate (<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate, <kbd>R</kbd> + 30 to rotate 30° (you can rotate by 30° every new duplicated piece). You can also do it with less steps if you want (it's easy to figure out how).
- Then you just need to select all pieces and insert keyframe (rotation + position). you can do it pressing <kbd>I</kbd>
- Move a new frame and move all the pieces to create the TIME word. Remember to use <kbd>I</kbd> to insert final keyframes (object by object).
- If you want to create some dynamic movements you can play with interpolation modes or frames (for example you can setup the scene so not all the objects start moving at the same frame).